# Can one deliver an electron application without delivering the debugger?

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I've shallow-researched this and could not get any answers. I have been able to use the *electron-packager* (assume latest) to package my electron application, but I don't want to deliver DevTools as a feature to the end-user. I recognize that you can disable it, but are there any electron configuration options that I could modify to not deliver DevTools or is it something that would be managed by the electron packager module?

Comment: What "debugger"? You mean the DevTools?

Comment: Yes, DevTools. Thank you.

Comment: I've never seen any mention of "removing" the DevTools – I thought it was a part of Chrome, the underlying browser in Electron – but disabling it means the user can't access it – so that comes to the same thing, imo.